# Import XML character styles into InDesign?

Tags: xml, adobe-indesign

### Summary

I'm attempting to import some XML into InDesign, tagged for paragraph and character styles. My paragraph styles are working fine, because each item entry has a firm, predictable structure; however, I can't get arbitrary character styles to work, as (within one paragraph) they can occur in any quantity or order.

Can you help me?

I can't seem to find this addressed in the Adobe documentation.

### More Detail

My XML looks something like this:

```
<root>
  <item>
    <title>Lorem <italic>ipsum</italic> dolor.</title>
    <description><italic>Consectetur.</italic> Ut vel <bold>aliquet.</bold> Maecenas non leo, <italic>in congue.</italic></description>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title><italic>Aenean leo</italic>, interdum <italic>in fermentum.</italic></title>
    <description><bold>Excepteur.</bold> Non proident, sunt in <italic>mollit anim id est</italic> labore et dolore.</description>
  </item>
</root>
```

I have tagged my InDesign file with equivalent tags:

Structure

- root
- item

Paragraph Styles

- title
- description

Character Styles

- italic
- bold

In the XML, say in the **description** field of the first **item**, two **italic** sections occur with a **bold** between them (among other, non-styled text).  However, in the second **item**, the **italic** follows a single **bold**.  I can't figure out how to tag the template to allow for arbitrary passages like this... it's not like the **italic** spans show up in the same place for each record.

In addition, the  passages occur in either or both of the **title** and **description** fields.

Does this require some JavaScript?  I'm not sure where to begin down that road, as text that doesn't match the predefined tagging structure doesn't even make it into my document after import.  In other words, there's nothing to process.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://www.indesignusergroup.com/chapters/brisbane/files/643/Brisbane_Handout.pdf) article gives a good overview of mapping XML tags to styles. It shouldn't require any Javascript to get this to work. I recently worked on a project that involved mapping XML tags to styles and works pretty effectively for small documents.

You have to ask yourself what each XML element will represent in the actual InDesign document. Will your `item` tags be represented by a text frame? Or will your `root` tag be represented by the text frame?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look, and I appreciate the whitepaper.  I finished the project with some kluges, and it never quite worked perfectly; plenty of manual style-adding in the InDesign document. My "root" tag was indeed the text frame. Styles inside "root" worked fine when each had a discreet paragraph (like the "item" tag), but within a paragraph, only the first character style would work.

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer for this here:
http://carijansen.com/indesign-xml-reference-guide/

snip:

> Mapping XML tags to styles, creates a link between content marked up
>   with an XML tag and a paragraph, character style, table or cell style
>   and will subsequently format the run-in XML data in the InDesign
>   document based on the mapping references.
>
> To map XML tags to various InDesign styles:
>
> 1. Select **Map Tags to Styles** from the Tags panel menu or the Structure
>      pane menu.
>
> All Tags available in the Tags panel are listed. The Style
>   menu provides a drop-down menu next to each Tag that contains a list
>   of all Paragraph, Character, Table and Cell Styles to which Tags may
>   be mapped.
>
> 2. Click **Map by Name** in the Map Tags to Styles dialog box to automatically map matching Tag and Style names. All matching names are automatically linked up. For any Tags not mapped, you can choose an alternative mapping option from the drop down-menu.
> 3. After you’ve linked all used tags to document styles, click OK. Imported XML data is formatted now automatically formatted using the matched paragraph, character, table and cell styles.